# What does 'for' in `uri_for` mean?

Tags: semantics, subroutine, catalyst

In [Catalyst](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Catalyst_%28software%29), I don't understand what does the *for* means in the `$c->URI_for();` subroutine.

Is it an abbrev for *for + something* (could be *forward*), an acronym or something ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It means the URI for whatever that particular `$c` is.

> `$c->uri_for( $path, @args?, \%query_values? )`
>
> Merges path with `$c->request->base` for absolute URIs and with `$c->namespace` for relative URIs, then returns a normalized URI object. If any args are passed, they are added at the end of the path. If the last argument to `uri_for` is a hash reference, it is assumed to contain GET parameter key/value pairs, which will be appended to the URI in standard fashion.
>
> Instead of `$path`, you can also optionally pass a `$action` object which will be resolved to a path using `$c->dispatcher->uri_for_action`; if the first element of `@args` is an arrayref it is treated as a list of captures to be passed to `uri_for_action`.

In terms of French, think of it in terms of `pour`, as in `Nom pour le livre` (name for the book) although, given it's been some twenty years since I last actually spoke French, I may have inadverdently insulted your heritage :-)

Answer (score 2):

The `for` in [`uri_for`](https://metacpan.org/module/Catalyst#c-uri_for-path-args-query_values-) is not an acronym. Read it like:

- URI for path
- URI for action